# Visual studio 2010 stuck

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've opened a XAML file in VS2010 that crashes Visual Studio.

The problem is that when I close VS and reload it again the XAML file automatically opens and crashes my VS again.

I don't know how to solve this loop.

Is there a way to open the solution with all files closed?

Comment: Rename the XAML file so that it isn't opened the next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could delete your solution's '***.suo**' file. This file contain the information about the open editors. If you delete it visual Studio will not open any editor when loading the solution.

However you might lose some other customizations as well but in general there is nothing really important in this file and Visual studio will automatically create a new .suo file

Answer (score 2):

I will try even a more violent method.
Move it into trash, and then bring up Visual Studio 2010.
Open another file in Visual Studio so your XAML file opening record will be washed out by the new one.
Close Visual Studio, and then restore your XAML file.

I'm pretty sure that Microsoft's file system won't track where your XAML file go and then tell Visual Studio to open it in the new location, but putting it in trash temporally is a great option.

Comment: @Roger Lipscombe - That'll work too, that's how we hacked a lot of the system files. Renaming, Replacing, and Deleting. But you should probably figure out how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try temporarily move the xaml file to another location. (or rename) so VS cant find it, then you should be able to open.